# Hibernate Exception in multithreading - Transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting *org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started* for the below mentioned code which is under concurrent execution(multithreaded).

```
Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    session = getSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DataItem.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("displayName", displayName));
    DataItem dataItem = (DataItem) criteria.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
    return dataItem;
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    if ( tx != null ) tx.rollback();
    String errorMsg = getResourceString( CONFIG_READ_ERROR );
    logger.error( errorMsg, e );
    throw new ConfigException( errorMsg, e);
} finally {      
    if(!tx.wasCommitted()) {
        tx.commit();
    }
    if ( session != null ) session.close();
}
```

Error is poping out from *tx.commit* in finally block. Below is root error stack trace:

> org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:131)

My suspicion is something went wrong with transaction as mentioned code block is under parallel execution. Can anyone please point out what is the fault code flow?

**getSession method**

```
protected Session getSession() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = BuildSessionFactory.getSessionFactory();
    Interceptor interceptor = BuildSessionFactory.getSessionInterceptor();
    if (connection != null) return sessionFactory.openSession(connection,interceptor);
    return sessionFactory.openSession(interceptor);
}
```

Comment: Can you post `getSession()` source code?

Comment: connection is a global variable

Comment: Please move the comment to your question body.

Comment: I see you only make a read only operation. You can remove the transaction stuff.

Comment: Yes It's only a read operation. will remove transaction stuff and see. Does it fetch data for multiple threads at a time?

Comment: Why not? Also, `SessionFactory` is thread safe and quite costly to create, you can share the same instance.